# noob needs help looping arrays

Tags: arrays, loops

I'm very new to JavaScript, ive been reading a book as well as pluralsights courses. i followed how the instructor looped his arrays but i didnt want to use the exact variables and values. When i try to do it on my own. i end up getting errors. even though my code looks basically the same. 
i guess the question here is. What am I missing?

```js
let shirts = ["red shirt", "green shirt" , "blue shirt", "flanel", "black shirt"];

let jeans = [ "blue jeans", "shorts", "sweatpants", "khakis"];
let outfit = [];
    
for( let shirtsIdx = 0; shirtsIdx < shirts.length; shirtsIdx++) {
  for ( let jeansIdx = 0; jeansIdx < jeans.length; jeansIdx++) {
    outfit.push(jeans[jeansIdx] + " and " shirts[shirtsIdx]);
  }
}

for ( let i = 0; i < outfit.length; i++) {
  console.log(outfit[i]);
}
```

Comment: "i end up getting errors" - what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a plus sign:

```
outfit.push(jeans[jeansIdx] + " and " + shirts[shirtsIdx]);
```

```js
var shirts = ["red shirt", "green shirt" , "blue shirt", "flanel", "black shirt"];
var jeans = [ "blue jeans", "shorts", "sweatpants", "khakis"];
var outfit = [];

for( var shirtsIdx = 0; shirtsIdx < shirts.length; shirtsIdx++) {
  for ( var jeansIdx = 0; jeansIdx < jeans.length; jeansIdx++) {
    outfit.push(jeans[jeansIdx] + " and " + shirts[shirtsIdx]);
  }
}

for ( var i = 0; i < outfit.length; i++) {
  console.log(outfit[i]);
}
```

Comment: ... kill myself.